# Why is this counting way wrong, aces drawn from two halves of a shuffled deck

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've got confused about the question. There are several same questions, still I got confused.

> A deck of cards is shuffled and then divided into two halves of 26 cards each. A card is drawn from one of the halves; it turns out to be an ace. The ace is then placed in the second half-deck. The half is then shuffled, and a card is drawn from it. Compute the probability that this drawn card is an ace.

My thought is: As the distribution of the initial condition is equally likely, we have probability $
\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{1}{26}
$ of dividing it into "1,3", and take 1 outo $\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{2}{26},\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{3}{26},\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{4}{26}
$ of other three. The denominator should be the sum of them. Thus, by conditional probability, the result is $
\frac{\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{1}{26}*\frac{4}{27}+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{2}{26}*\frac{3}{27}+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{3}{26}*\frac{2}{27}+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{4}{26}*\frac{1}{27}}{\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{1}{26}+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{2}{26}+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 3\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 1\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{3}{26}+\frac{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
 26\\
 0\\
\end{array} \right)}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 52\\
 4\\
\end{array} \right)}*\frac{4}{26}}
$

It seems that this answer is not equal to the correct probability. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: the probability of a 1-3 split originally is $(\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{25})/\binom{52}{26}$.

Comment: @MatthewDalyM When expanding, it seems like these two expressions are the same number.

Comment: I apologize.  I did not suspect that they would be the same.

Comment: I think your answer is correct (and agrees with the answer of Daniel). Note that the denominator equals $\frac1{13}$. What makes you think that it is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It seems that this answer is not equal to the correct probability."

I seems to me that your answer is correct.

For $k=0,1,2,3,4$ let $A_{k}$ denote the event that there are $k$
aces among the $26$ cards from which a card is drawn at first hand.

Let $E$ be the event that this first drawn card is an ace.

Let $F$ denote the event that the second card drawn is an ace.

Then $P\left(E\right)=\frac{1}{13}$ and to be found is $P\left(F\mid E\right)=P\left(F\cap E\right)/P\left(E\right)=13P\left(F\cap E\right)$.

This can be solved by:$$P\left(F\mid E\right)=13P\left(F\cap E\right)=$$$$13\sum_{k=0}^{4}P\left(F\mid E\cap A_{k}\right)P\left(E\mid A_{k}\right)P\left(A_{k}\right)=13\sum_{k=0}^{4}\frac{5-k}{27}\frac{k}{26}\frac{\binom{26}{k}\binom{26}{4-k}}{\binom{52}{4}}=$$$$\frac1{54}\binom{52}{4}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{4}(5-k)k\binom{26}{k}\binom{26}{4-k}$$

This answer agrees with the (nice!) answer of Daniel Mathias (check it e.g. in Excel) and only differs from yours by the fact that you took a more complicated route by calculation of  $P(E)$.

There you went for: $$P(E)=\sum_{k=1}^4P(E\cap A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^4P(A_k)P(E\mid A_k)$$ which also results in $P(E)=\frac1{13}$

Comment: Thanks! Maybe there's something fo wring when tapping the calculator...

Answer (score 1):

The probability of drawing the same card (i.e. the ace drawn from the first half) is $\frac{1}{27}$ and the probability of drawing any other card is $\frac{26}{27}$ and each of these cards has probability $\frac{3}{51}=\frac{1}{17}$ to be an ace.

The total probability is $\frac{1}{27}+\frac{26}{27}\times\frac{1}{17}=\frac{43}{459}$

Comment: Yeah I know this solution. I just merely wonder where I get wrong.

Comment: +1 Nice solution.